# create a json from array of string using javascript

Tags: javascript

After scraping an html table I have stored my data in the variable:

```
var data = ["header1", "header2", "a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "c1", "c2"];
```

I want to create a json file in the form:

```js
var json = [
  {
    "header1":"a1", 
    "header2":"a2"
  },
  {
    "header1":"b1", 
    "header2":"b2"
  },
  {
    "header1":"c1", 
    "header2":"c2"
  }
]
```

I know that I need

```
var headers={};
```

and load it with

```
headers["header1"]
headers["header2"]
```

I also need

```
var jsonObj = [];
```

and push the array headers inside jsonObj:

```
jsonObj.push(headers);
```

Is it possible to create it?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON array" (or ["JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)). `json` is an array of objects. There's no [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) at all in your question.

Comment: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: I have a large number of data in my real code and I am trying to understand how to loop in the array of strings and "isolate" the headers..

Comment: How can you distinguish headers from data?

Comment: I know headers are data[0] and data[1]

Comment: It's always two columns but unspecified rows?

Comment: yes thre are always two columns

Comment: How do you differentiate between which value going to header1 and which one to header2?

Comment: It is always like that.. First two elements are my headers and then data[2], data[4] .. go to header1 and data[3], data[5]... go to header2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make some assumptions, and then attempt to answer your question.

To me, it seems your table looks something like:

| header1 | header2 |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | a2 |
| b1 | b2 |
| c1 | c2 |

Simply starting with the array you already have, we can then just pick out two and two values at the time. See the code below

```js
const COLUMN_COUNT = 2
const data = ["header1", "header2", "a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "c1", "c2"]

// this removes the headers from the data-list, 
// and stores them in the headers variable
const headers = data.splice(0, COLUMN_COUNT)
const output = []

while(data.length > 0) {
  const row = {}
  const values = data.splice(0, COLUMN_COUNT)
  for(const [idx, value] of values.entries()) {
    const header = headers[idx]
    row[header] = value
  }
  output.push(row)
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Correct. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no relation between header and the values, but assuming the first two elements are always `header1 and header2` and the next 1 pair will be the value of header1 and header2 respectively, this might do it

```js
const data = ["header1", "header2", "a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "c1", "c2"];
const res = [];
const h1 = data[0];
const h2 = data[1];
data.splice(0, 2);


for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        const payload = {};
        payload[h1] = data[i - 1];
        payload[h2] = data[i];
        res.push(payload);
    }
}

console.log(res)
```